# Why does my tf.gather() have no batch_dims attribute?

Tags: tensorflow

In the official tensorflow document, `gather_nd()` has the `batch_dims` attribute. Why does my `gather_nd()` look like this: `gather_nd(params, indices, name=None)`

Comment: Tf vesions in doc and installed on your host is the same?

Comment: @Andrew Thanks.It works after I update my tf version.